# Is there a possible way to load a Oracle .dmp file to an SQL Server 2012?

Tags: oracle

This throws me the below error:

> the media family on device is incorrectly formed 3241.

I tried loading the .dmp file as .bak file and restored the db. It did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I know to extract from dmp is to use the "INDEXFILE" parameter for IMP, this will generate a readable SQL script with the DDL and DML.

However often times this script is not 100% usable as it (usually) wraps the statements, so some pre-processing may be required, for example parse the file by each discrete statement (INSERT, CREATE), join each statement into a single line then squirt into the target database. Having said that, you would probably need to pre-process anyway to translate Oracle to SQL server dialogue anyway.

Also, might not be so good for BLOB/binary type data.

The other indirect way to do this would be to create a bridge Oracle database, import the file into there, then use the normal extract and load tools to push the data into SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

A `*.dmp` file in `Oracle` is nothing but a backup file. You meant to say restoring a Oracle DB backup file in `SQL Server`.

AFAIK, the answer is *NO*. You can't do that. Probably you can check, if there is any third party utility present using which you can perform a DB migration.

Answer (score 0):

The `dmp` file comes in an Oracle specific format that cannot be parsed/interpreted by anything other than Oracle's `imp` tool. So, that means you cannot import the dmp file into SQL Server.

Of course there are ways to transfer data from Oracle to SQL Server but which one is optimal depends on your needs, amount of data, number of tables, number of Oracle schemas, datatypes etc etc.